# Updating UIProgressView using GCD - Correct Timing - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have a UIProgress view which I want to update as an NSXML Parser runs. The NSXML parser is running on the main thread and takes about 30 seconds to run.

At the end of a parsing section I call a method in my app delegate :

```
[appDelegate updateLoadingScreen:0.75];
```

The app delegate then calls the modelLoadingProgressUpdate method in the loadingScreen :

```
- (void)updateLoadingScreen : (float)progress {
NSLog(@"PROGRESS REQUEST !!!");

NSNumber * progressNS = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress];

[loadingScreen modelLoadingProgressUpdate : progressNS];

}
```

The modelLoadingProgressUpdate method then uses a dispatch queue to update the UIProgressBar :

```
- (void) modelLoadingProgressUpdate :(NSNumber *)progress {

dispatch_queue_t mainqueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_async(mainqueue, ^  { 

float updateProgress = [progress floatValue];
NSLog(@"Update Progress is %f", updateProgress);

progressView.progress = updateProgress;

});

}
```

However nothing is updating on my UIProgressView. The `modelLoadingProgressUpdate` seems to only trigger once the parser has completed.

Can anyone spot what is wrong ?

Comment: If you're running with breakpoints enabled, can you spot that progressView.progress actually points to an instance of a progress view when you call it in your dispatch_async?

Comment: Yes - it's wired up via an IBOutlet which is working - if I set the value prior to the start of the NSXMLParser then it updates ok, so it must be my dispatch queue timing.

Comment: What exactly does happen with the bar? Does it never fill at all? Does it go from 0 to 100% in one motion?

Comment: Never fills at all - stuck at default value of 0.5 as in xib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

> The NSXML parser is running on the main thread and takes about 30 seconds to run.

So your NSXMLParser is blocking the main thread, so the block that you dispatch isn't being executed until the NSXMLParser is done.

Since the NSXMLParser is running on the main thread anyway, you could just get rid of the `dispatch_async` and just update `progressView.progress` directly in `modelLoadingProgressUpdate:`.

Or, you can run the NSXMLParser on a background thread, in which case it won't block the main thread and the progress updating block will run soon after you dispatch it.

Comment: Hi Yuji. If I try updating directly on the main thread the progress view still doesn't update until the xml parser has finished.

Comment: That's firing correctly - logs every time I send an update request.

Comment: The reason setting your progress view directly isn't working is that, again, you are blocking the main thread. The progress view will not draw the changes until you have stopped using the main thread. Setting the values directly is bad advise. However the rest of this answer is correct. You really should never ever run a 30 second synchronous task on the main thread.